# Find the order of zero at z=0

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f(z) = $\frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{2z}$ $-$ 1, show that the order of zero at z=0.

My work: order of zero at z=0 is the largest n $\in$ $\mathcal{N}$ such that $\frac{g(z)}{2z-0}$ extends to a holomorphic function at z=0, where g(z) = e$^z$ $-$ e$^{-z}$ $-$ 2z

check: lim$_{z\rightarrow0}$(z$-$0)$\frac{e^z - e^{-z} - 2z}{(2z-0)^n}$ = $\frac{1}{2^n}$ lim$_{z\rightarrow0}$$\frac{e^z - e^{-z} - 2z}{z^{n-1}}$ = 
$\frac{1}{2^n}$ lim$_{z\rightarrow0}$$\frac{e^z + e^{-z} - 2}{(n-1)z^{n-2}}$ = 
$\frac{1}{2^n(n-1)}$ lim$_{z\rightarrow0}$$\frac{e^z + e^{-z} - 2}{z^{n-2}}$ = 
$\frac{1}{2^n(n-1)(n-2)}$ lim$_{z\rightarrow0}$$\frac{e^z - e^{-z}}{z^{n-3}}$ = 
$\frac{1}{2^n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$ lim$_{z\rightarrow0}$$\frac{e^z + e^{-z}}{z^{n-4}}$

the last term limit does not exist, so I conclude that the largest n should be 3. Thus the order of zero at z=0 is 3.

Is my work correct? if not, any help to do it correctly?

Comment: It's an even function of $z$.

Comment: $(2z)^n = 2^n \cdot z^n$

Comment: I think it is much easier to expand your numerator as a power series around zero and divide the series by $z$. Whatever the lowest power is in the resulting series is the order of your zero. I can write a formal answer if you do not know how that works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: your function is just
$$f(z)=\frac1z\sinh z-1=\frac1z\biggl(z+\frac {z^3}6+\dotsm\biggr)-1=\dots$$